# Cannot Add foreign key constraint Error 1215

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Workbench 6.0 and having a frustrating issue I am new to SQl and would like to keep this as simple as possible at this point, I believe my tables are ordered properly to add contraints except for my TICKET table, no idea how to find what foreign key is having problems.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACTION_TYPE (
ActionCode int primary key,
Description char(50) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OFFICER (
PersonnelNo int primary key,
OfficerLName char(50) not null,
OfficerFName char(50) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DRIVER (
DriverLicenseNo int primary key,
DriverLastName char(50) not null,
DriverFirstName char(50) not null,
DriverAddress char(50) not null,
DriverCity char(50) not null,
DriverProv char(50) not null,
DriverPostalCode varchar(6) not null,
DriverGender char(1) not null,
DriverBirthDate Date not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REGISTERED_OWNER (
RegOwnerID int primary key auto_increment,
RegOwnerLName char(50) not null,
RegOwnerFName char(50) not null,
RegOwnerAddress char(50) not null,
RegOwnerCity char(50) not null,
RegOwnerProv char(50) not null,
RegOwnerPostalCode varchar(6) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VEHICLE_TYPE (
VehicleType int primary key,
VehicleDescription char(50) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VEHICLE (
VehicleLicense int primary key,
ProvinceIssued char(2) not null,
VehicleYear int not null,
VehicleMake char(10) not null,
VehicleType int not null,
index (VehicleType),
foreign key (VehicleType)
    references VEHICLE_TYPE (VehicleType)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (      <-----this table calling the error
TicketNo int primary key auto_increment,
TicketDateTime datetime not null,
TicketLocationCity char(50) not null,
TicketLocationProv char(50) not null,
TicketLocationRoad char(50) not null,

PersonnelNo int not null,
VehicleLicense int not null,
ActionCode int not null,
RegOwnerID int not null,
DriversLicenseNo int not null,

index (PersonnelNo),
foreign key (PersonnelNo)
    references OFFICER (PersonnelNo),

index (VehicleLicense),
foreign key (VehicleLicense)
    references VEHICLE (VehicleLicense),

index (ActionCode),
foreign key (ActionCode)
    references ACTION_TYPE (ActionCode),

index (RegOwnerID),
foreign key (RegOwnerID)
    references REGISTERED_OWNER (RegOwnerID),

index (DriversLicenseNo),
foreign key (DriversLicenseNo)
    references DRIVER (DriversLicenseNo)

)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VIOLATION_TYPE (
ViolationCode int primary key auto_increment,
ViolationDesc char(50) not null,
ViolationCurrFineAmt int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VIOLATION (

ViolationNo int primary key auto_increment,
TicketNo int not null,
ViolationCode int not null,
AppliedFineAmount int not null,
index (TicketNo),
foreign key (TicketNo)
    references TICKET (TicketNo),
index (ViolationCode),
foreign key (ViolationCode)
    references VIOLATION_TYPE (ViolationCode)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.031 sec

Comment: Spelling mistake on DriverLicenseNo in TICKET table ane 
DriversLicenseNo in DRIVER table

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding that one, sorry for wasting time, I really didn't see that one even tho i scanned and scanned for spelling. time for sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling mistake on DriverLicenseNo in TICKET table ane 
DriversLicenseNo in DRIVER table